# mysql insert current_user() by default

Tags: mysql, default-value

I have a table like

create table try ( firstname varchar(4), username varchar(4))

My question is that is there a way to insert the current_user() or user() value in the username field by default.

So for example if I am logged in to the database as 'abcduser' then

> insert into try values( 'kashif');
>
> select * from try
>
> kashif abcduser

Is this possible , just how I can insert defualt timestamp by doing something like
ARRIVAL_TIME timestamp not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

is this is not possible, then what are the alternatives?

Comment: no. you'll have to use a trigger.

Comment: avoid triggers; they make design messy. Use them only when you can't change the existing design.

Comment: the mysql user? or is this for a website application?

Comment: yes I am taking about mysql user

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a table insert trigger with the USER() function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).